# Finding the smallest element in multidimensional array

Tags: c, math

Im asking for help once again. This time I found myself in the midst of a task which I found on the internet and I cant find a good solution. At first I thought of bubble sort, but I didnt seem to find a way to use it with multidimensional array.
The task asks to find 3 smallest elements which arent repeating on the second array.
So far my code looks like this, though Ive removed a lot of it... Since it was a very wrong and futile aproach.

Everything was written in C.
Thanks for the help.

```
3

1 2 3

3 3 3

3 3 3

5 4 6

6 4 5

4 5 6
```

This is the given information for the file

```
#include stdio.h
#include stdlib.h

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("Duomenys.txt", "r");
    int i, j;
    int k, l;
    int bubbleTmp;
    fscanf(fptr, "%d ", &k);
    l = k;
    int a[k][k];
    int b[k][k];

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fptr,"%d ",&a[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fptr,"%d ",&b[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Bubble Sort
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] > a[i][j+1])
            {

            }
        }
    }


    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the input file, or parts from it.

Comment: Written in C, so why the C++11 tag?

Comment: I assumed that C++ users would understand the code. Im trying to find the base logic behind finding the lowest members. Ill remove it asap, sorry.

Comment: No need to bubble sort, right?

Comment: The task indicates that the variables(elements) might change and that we need to find 3 smallest elements from the first multidimensional array, which wouldnt repeat in the second matrix. The information given was just an example. Also array size is dynamic, it could change. But Ill think of something with Dynamical Memory Allocation, as of now, just the logic behind the main part of it. Thanks for the answer though, I really appreciate it :) Bubble sort would be just fine, if you know how to modify it for a multidimensional array.

Comment: Your "bubble sort" just reads off the end of the current row, and doesn't have any operation to move entries between rows.  If you mean that the first row should have the smallest entries etc. then just treat your array like a long 1-D array and sort that.

Comment: Yeah... Thats why I removed most of it... Since I saw that itll only check rows. Thanks for the warn though :) Well... The excercise I found indicates that it requires me to use multidimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the minimum and its position in the array:

```
int min = a[0][0], i_min = 0, j_min = 0;

for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] < min)
            {
                min = a[i][j];
                i_min = i;
                j_min = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

After the first try, you repeat it two more times, avoiding the minimums alrerady found. The positions of each minimums are known.

Comment: Wow :o Thanks a lot. You made it so clear and so easy.

Comment: What do you mean? :o From this example I thought, it could be possible to use 2 more loops inside the if statement to check wether theyre repeating... Its an unoptimized program... But atleast it works. Although if you have a better solution that would be amazing! Again.. Thank you for your time you spent helping me guys

Answer (score 0):

Previously, it was a suggestion. 
Now, here is the solution:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int **CreateArray (int N, int M)
{
    int **arr = new int*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        arr[i] = new int [M];

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
            arr[i][j] = rand()%10 - rand()%10;

    return arr;
}

void DestroyArray (int **arr, int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        delete [] arr[i];
    delete [] arr;
}

void PrintArray (int **arr, int N, int M)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
            std::cout << std::setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct _min
{
    int value;
    int i;
    int j;
} TMin;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void FindMin (int **arr, int N, int M, TMin **mins, int min_count)
{
    mins[min_count]->value = arr[0][0];
    mins[min_count]->i = 0;
    mins[min_count]->j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j] < mins[min_count]->value)
            {
                bool prev = false;
                for (int k = 0; k<min_count; k++)
                    if (i == mins[k]->i && j == mins[k]->j)
                    {   
                        prev = true;
                        break;
                    }

                if (!prev)
                {   
                    mins[min_count]->value = arr[i][j];
                    mins[min_count]->i = i;
                    mins[min_count]->j = j;
                }
            }
        }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{   
        //array creation, filling, printing
        srand ((unsigned int)time (NULL));
        int N = 6, M = 7;
        int **arr = CreateArray (N, M);
        PrintArray (arr, N, M);

        //container for 3 minimums
        TMin **mins = new TMin*[3];
            for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                mins[i] = new TMin;

        //let us find them
        int min_count = -1;
        while (++min_count < 3)
            FindMin (arr, N, M, mins, min_count);

        //result
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
            std::cout << "arr[" << mins[i]->i << "][" <<mins[i]->j << "] = " << mins[i]->value << "\n";

        //cleaning memory
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
            delete [] mins[i];
        delete [] mins;

        DestroyArray (arr, N);

        std::cin.sync();
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```